# MVC - when Create PDF report and in Printed in Arabic language the result not understandable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, printing, pdf-generation

I'm using MVC , I wrote normal code to create my report as i used in asp.net before.

```
LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource);

        string MimeType;
        string Encoding;
        string FileNameExtension;
        Warning[] Warnings;
        string[] Streams;
        byte[] RendereBytes;

        RendereBytes = LocalReport.Render(
            ReportType,
            null, //DeviceInfo,
            out MimeType,
            out Encoding,
            out FileNameExtension,
            out Streams,
            out Warnings
            );


        return File(RendereBytes, MimeType);
```

[image]

but now in MVC my Arabic litters coming as you see in attached pic ... 
this problem coming sometimes not always ... if you reprint it will coming good without any problem.
My problem in arabic only in english.

any one knows why???

Comment: plz see example pic
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JXYe.jpg

Comment: My problem in arabic only not in english